# Convert unit vector from body to ECEF coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, elevation, direction, azimuth

I have an Android phone using local coordinate system as shown on the picture:
[image: Illustrative graphic of the device, its system of Cartesian axes and its angles of rotation.]

"Азимут" is azimuth.
"Угол места" is elevation.
"Крен" is roll.

Azimuth is measured from geographic north, clockwise. Elevation is measured from horizontal plane. When phone looks at North - azimuth is 0, when it looks at the horizon - elevation is 0.

Please, tell me what DCMs could I use in order to convert the unit vector:
[cos(az)*cos(el), sin(el), sin(az)*cos(el)]

from local (body) to ECEF coordinate system.

P.S. Device position in lat/long/alt is also known.

Comment: Azimuth is measured from geographic North? Elevation is measured from horizontal plane or nadir?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca , Azimuth is measured from geographic north, clockwise. Elevation is measured from horizontal plane. When phone looks at North - azimuth is 0, when it looks at the horizon - elevation is 0.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca added the missing information

Comment: Assuming negligible vertical deviation (with respect to the normal to the ellipsoid), your system can be conveniently brought to a topocentric system. I don't know what you mean by DCMs, but section 4.1.2 of [IOGP Report 373-07-02 – Coordinate conversions and transformation including formulas](https://www.iogp.org/bookstore/product/coordinate-conversions-and-transformation-including-formulas/) will surely be useful to you.